# R Shiny | Set up an editable data frame to be able to make a plot later

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, reactive

I'm trying to set up a dataframe based on the output of a sliderInput.

Here is my code:

```
runApp(
  list(
    ui = dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "Crédit"),
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Visualisation des données", tabName = "visualization", icon = icon("poll"))
        )),
      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
          # visualization
          tabItem(tabName = "visualization",
                  h1("Visualisation des données"),
                  h2("Exploration du tableau"),
                  dataTableOutput('dataTable'),
                  h2("Graphiques"),
                  fluidRow(
                    column(5, plotOutput("Plot1")),
                    column(4,dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"),
                                            start = as.Date("1972-09-30"))
                       ),
                    column(4,
                           sliderInput("slider", label = h3("Slider"), min = 0, 
                                       max = 5, value = 1, step = 0.5),
                    column(6,
                          dataTableOutput('my_table')
                    )))
          )
        )))
    , server = function(input, output) {
      myReactives <- reactiveValues(credit = Credit_Defaut)
      output$dataTable = DT::renderDataTable(Credit_Defaut[1:100,])
      a <- reactive({as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, nrow = (length(seq(0,10,input$slider))-1), ncol = 1))})
      b <- reactive({as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, nrow = (length(seq(0,10,input$slider))-1), ncol = 1))})
      df <- reactive({as.data.frame(matrix(data = c(paste0("[", seq(0,10,input$slider)[1],";",seq(0,10,input$slider)[2],"]"),
                                                    for (i in 2:(length(seq(0,10,input$slider))-2)){
                                                      a()[i-1] <- paste0("]", seq(0,10,input$slider)[i],";",seq(0,10,input$slider)[i+1],"]")},a(),
                                                    paste0("]", max(seq(0,10,input$slider)),";","Inf","["),
                                                    nrow(myReactives$credit[which(myReactives$credit$Defaut>=seq(0,10,input$slider)[1] & myReactives$credit$Defaut<=seq(0,10,input$slider)[2]),]),
                                                    for (i in 2:(length(seq(0,10,input$slider))-2)){
                                                      b()[i-1] <- nrow(myReactives$credit[which(myReactives$credit$Defaut>seq(0,10,input$slider)[i] & myReactives$credit$Defaut<=seq(0,10,input$slider)[i+1]),])},
                                                    b(),
                                                    nrow(myReactives$credit[which(myReactives$credit$Defaut>max(seq(0,10,input$slider))),])),nrow = (length(seq(0,10,input$slider))-1), ncol = 2))})
      output$my_table  <- renderDataTable({
        df()
      })
    }))
```

First of all, I just want to check that I am getting the correct data frame. But I have the following error:

```
Warning: Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

I think this is due to my "a" and my "b" for my for loop. I don't know if I am calling them correctly in my vector.

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Thank you in advance for the people who will invest in my problem.

Comment: if I hear about "editable data.frame for Shiny" I think about `rhandsontable`

Comment: After looking, I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I would just like to take into account the output of a SliderInput in order to create a dataframe by using it when designing it.
But thank you for offering this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to the result of a reactive function :

```
# Correct:
a <- reactive({as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, nrow = (length(seq(0,10,input$slider))-1), ncol = 1))})

# Wrong:
a()[i-1] <- paste0(...)
```

You could create a temporary array and then fill it :

```
reactive({
  a_ <- a()
  a_[i-1] <- paste0(...)
  ...
})
```

Same problem with b()

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I take your solution into account. However, I have the impression that these are manipulations that I cannot do when I am not with reactive. `a <- reactive({as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, nrow = (length(seq(0,10,input$slider))-1), ncol = 1))})
      b <- reactive({as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, nrow = (length(seq(0,10,input$slider))-1), ncol = 1))})
      a_ <- a()
      b_ <- b()`

Comment: This is correct, you can only use reactive functions in other reactive expressions, I clarified my edit

Comment: Great, thank you ! Now there is also a problem in the content of my matrix. The vector takes only the first value and duplicates it. Here is the error: `Warning in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , j, value = list("[0;1]", c("]1;2]",  :
  provided 10 variables to replace 1 variables
Warning in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , j, value = list(31385L, c(36492L,  :
  provided 10 variables to replace 1 variables`

Comment: I have the impression that it is during the for loop, with the exit. In the error we can easily see that it finds the term I want, but that it does not take it in the vector because of an error.

Comment: OK perfect, please consider accepting my partial answer so that others can also benefit from it.